# Display warning message between hours in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

In my application (PHP) i need to show the warning message between 23:00:00 to 05:00:00 hrs. How to write a condition for the above scenario because start time is today and end time will be tomorrow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't bother about date, the time is all you need:

```
$currentHour = (int) date('H');

if ($currentHour >= 23 || $currentHour < 5) {
    // warning here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please see the below code.

You have to specify the correct timezone. Otherwise the message will be displayed in unexpected time.

```
$timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$hour = date("H");
if($hour >= 23 || $hour < 5)
{
    echo "Error Message";
}
```

Cheers!

Prasad

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a simple check. Just see if the hour of the day is either smaller then 5 or 23 or larger, like this:

```
if(date('H') < 5 || date('H') >= 23) {
    echo 'WARNING!';
}
```